# Как задать margin: 0 auto; position absolute

Tags: html, css

Как задать margin: 0px auto; position: absolute; 
Проблема в том, что элемент в центр не становится

Comment: elem {margin: 0px auto; position: absolute;}

Comment: в таких ситуациях нужен не развернутый вопрос, а фиддл с примером проблемного кода

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если блок фиксированый:

http://jsfiddle.net/yALWA/

Отрицательные margin равны половине высоты/ширины блока